# Background-image:inherit and HTTP Requests

Tags: http, request

I Tried to find the answers here on stackoverflow but couldent find it , so I hope someone can help me.

The question is pretty simple I guess, Im trying to optimize My site with a image sprite instead of many images.
And I wanted to know if a background:inherit counts as HTTP Request?

Was thinking otherwise I could let My DIVs just inherit the first DIVs background image and save me a lot of Requests.

And do Two img links too the same image sprite count as one or Two HTTP Request? I mean do the browser understand that it already download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you cache images, two (or a thousand) image links will only issue one HTTP Request, as long as the image itself doesn't change, though it's really about the **browser** implementation. The same goes about using inheritance or even using the same resource in different CSS elements. If you are using Chrome, I'd suggest that you'll take a look at the network tab in the Developer tools and verify that this is indeed the case. Otherwise, you can try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

If you'll share a link, I'd be more than happy to take a look at it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but its on the localhost Only atm. Marking this a solved!